# Change UIlabel title text in ZDCLoadingErrorView

Tags: zendesk

I need to change title UIlabel text in ZDCLoadingErrorView when no agent is available, but unable to do that.

Using  ZDCChat.instance().offlineMessageHandler.noAgentsMessage , I am only able to change message UIlabel in  ZDCLoadingErrorView.

ZDCLoadingErrorView.init().title return nil and I havn't found any way to add notification for ZDCLoadingErrorView when it first appears.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can change it through the Localizable.strings file located at the ZDCChatStrings.bundle. The key is "ios.ZDCChat.noAgentsTitle" as stated on https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/ios-chat-sdk/customization